# Video driver slows down after Adobe flash crashes

Tags: windows-7, video, 64-bit, flash, thinkpad

I have this really weird and annoying problem. Sometimes, not always video playback makes Flash crash in the browser (I use Chrome 19.0.1084.46 Official Build 135956 but as far as I remember it is the same with Firefox it seems like Adobe flash video playback and the Video driver hate each other sometimes) on Windows 7, 64 bit. The hardware is a Lenovo Thinkpad x201s, the driver is Intel hd 8.15.10.2401. Once this happens, the whole machine slows down, but I could check in task manager on the performance tab and it is not the CPU (it stays below 10%).
It looks like it is the video driver which gets screwed up. I tried to change resolution, but it did not fix it, only restart does. The video refresh is so slow, that I press and hold alt-tab for task list and it takes about 10 seconds to draw the items, and I can see how every about 50 pixel wide rows are being drawn/refreshed.

I was suspecting the video chip is getting too hot, but first of all it is all good straight after restart and second I can watch HD movies for hours without problem with a standalone player, the problem only comes with browser+flash based video playback and it comes within 5-10 minutes (when it comes, not always).

Checked for viruses and ran a full memory test with memtest86.
I recently re-installed Windows 7 and it did not fix this problem.

I've checked and 8.15.10.2401 is the latest version of the video driver. I reinstalled the driver again today.

Im really frustrated, because can not take in for warranty service as first of all they claim it is a software issue, and second they can not reproduce the problem as it only comes once in a while (well, often enough to make me annoyed once or twice so every other day)

If anyone experienced similar issues and/or could suggest what to test, what to update/check for, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated the graphics driver to 8.15.10.2509 from Intel directly http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20391 hope and pray this is going to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the graphics driver to 8.15.10.2509 from Intel directly fixed it

Comment: So it took you three months to update the drivers? :p

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ideal solution...but after updating the driver I noticed doesn't have to restart the PC to fix this - just unload and reload the drivers.